# 1.3+0.13 calculation in Python

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

I want to make a script in Python that has to do some relatively simple calculation. I noticed that some very simple additions like 1.3+0.13 yield strange results (1.4300000000000002 for this example).

Is this a known issue? Is there a way to avoid it?

To test it by yourself:

```
print (1.3+0.13)
```

Comment: Floating point is inherently imprecise. If you're working to a known number of decimal places then scale the numbers up to avoid the point.

Comment: You can also check the `decimal` library in python.  `print(Decimal('1.3') + Decimal('.13')) >> 1.43`